# Why does $\lim_{n \to \infty} x^{1+1/(2n-1)}=|x|$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Consider the following limit for $x \in [-1,1]$ and $n \in \mathbb N$:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} x^{1+\frac{1}{2n-1}}=|x|$$

I can't see where does the absolute value come from. Why isn't the answer simply $x$?

> This limit is available on page 156 of Abbott's Understanding Analysis.

EDIT: Sorry i found a dublicate [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/767959/137035).

Comment: I suspect there is a typo and there should be an absolute value on the left as well. Else for negative $x$ the LHS will sometimes be imaginary.

Comment: How do you define the rational power of a negative number?

Comment: No, it's not true, it's false.

Comment: I don't know if there is a typo I have included the source.

Comment: I cant see in which way is this $|x|$

Comment: @giomasce I can't really catch what you mean.

Comment: The nearest thing I can think of is that $x = e ^{\log x}$, which is a frequent trick of finding limits iff $x>0$

Comment: @i.ozturk What is it ${(-0.5)}^{\frac{9}{10}}$?

Comment: aha got it there is no mistake in the question

Comment: @giomasce From the perspective of an engineer, it seems math error to me.

Comment: @i.ozturk Then the limit is not defined for negative values of $x$, since you have to compute terms like that.

Comment: But you don't - the roots are always odd. There is no problem in evaluating cube roots, fifth roots, etc for negative numbers

Comment: @tomi If it is ok for you to define that way odd roots of negative numbers, that it works. But conceptually this is not so obvious. And you have to understand this in order to give the answer.

Comment: Agree with previous posters. There must be a typo. Fractional powers of negative numbers aren't uniquely defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can also be done this way :
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x^{1+ \frac{1}{2n-1}}= \lim_{n\to\infty}x^{\frac{2n-1+1}{2n-1}}= \lim_{n\to\infty}x^{\frac{2n}{2n-1}}$$
$$= \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(x^2\right)^{\frac{n}{2n-1}}= \left(x^2\right)^{ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{2n-1}}$$
$$= \left(x^2\right)^{ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{2-\frac1n}}= \left(x^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2-0}} = \left(x^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt{x^2}$$
Since, $x\in [-1,1]$
$$=|x|$$

Hence proved

Comment: It's impossible to start simplifying without specifying the set, and for negative x, fractional powers aren't even uniquely defined.

Comment: @mathreadler i have edited it

Comment: Your answer seems very reasonable but there should be some rules about taking this limit. Even Wolfram gives $x$. What do we do wrong when finding $x$ as a result?

Comment: @i.ozturk i cant see a way how wolfram gives x

Comment: Using your argument you could claim ${(-1)}^2^{1/4} = 1$, but that's not true either, since it is usually defined as the imaginary unit i.

Comment: @mathreadler if you compute what you just wrote it is both i and 1

Comment: It is not allowed to be both 1 and i, since those are two different numbers. You are doing something wrong. Try and find what.

Comment: what is (-1)^2 it is 1 and 1^(1/4) is 1@mathreadler

Comment: the other way around it can also be written as (-1)^1/2 which is i

Comment: That's an argument of why your way of manipulating the numbers is incorrect.

Comment: You need to be more strict defining your branches or you end up barking the wrong tree (or computing the wrong function).

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: key point here is that there is $2n-1$ as the denominator. This is not by accident...

Let's call $y_n=x^{\frac{1}{2n-1}}$

$y_n^{2n-1}=x$ has the same sign as $y_n$, since $2n-1$ is even.

For $x<0$, $y_n^{2n-1}=-|x|$,   $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

$y_n$ can be written as (since it has the same sign as $y_n^{2n-1}):

$y_n=-|x|^{\frac{1}{2n-1}}$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n=-1$

Thus

$\lim_{n \to \infty} |x|^{1+\frac{1}{2n-1}}=-x=|x|$

This solves the case $x<0$. The other case is obvious.

Answer (score -1):

|x| implies x < 0 0r x > 0, i.e. x has a possibility of being either. 1/(2n - 1) approaches 0 as n -> infinity and therefore the limit is x^1 since x^0 = 1, and then it follows that if x < 0, this limit is negative and positive is x > 0. All it means is that x can be positive or negative.

Comment: This is not what is meant by $|x|$.$|x|$ is a function that takes in positive or negative numbers and gives out a positive number that is the magnitude of the original number. It can be replicated on a simple scientific calculator by first squaring a number and then finding the square root.$|x|=\sqrt{(x^2)}$