# $\lim_{n\to\infty} x^{1+\frac{1}{2n+1}} = |x|$ on the set $[-1,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, functions

How does $\lim_{n\to\infty} x^{1+\frac{1}{2n+1}} = |x|$ on the set $[-1,1]$?

I have $$\lim_{n\to\infty} x^{1+\frac{1}{2n+1}} = x(\lim_{n\to\infty}x^{\frac{1}{2n+1}}) = x\cdot x^0 = x$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you define, say, $x^{4/3}$ for $x<0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/767959/limit-of-h-nx-x1-frac12n-1).
Basically we have $x^{\frac{2n+2}{2n+1}}=(x^2)^ {\frac{n+1}{2n+1}}$. Then take the limit and you will have your answer.